# Is it possible to run a program by downloading the source folder in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, runtime, antbuilder

I was curious if it is possible to run a project in a different desktop by just downloading the source folder and setting it as the workspace?

If possible, how can I run it? When I try, an ant-builder shows up when running it.

Any help would be nice,
Thank you.

Comment: Why are you ignoring the help you've received in this and in your other questions? For example, why have you not commented on any answer given here? Why have you not up-voted any? Why not accept the single best one? Please help those (volunteers all) who try to help you.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download the source code project.
2. Import the project in eclipse.
3. Project>Clean>Build
4. Run

Answer (score 0):

Downloading the workspace is probably not a good idea, since you might have different environment and locations.

What I would do is this:

1. Create a new workspace or use an existing one
2. Open the workspace above
3. Use File -> Import ->Existing project to a workspace
4. Navigate to the root folder of the project that you want to import

Alternatively in step #4 you can navigate to a root folder of several project, in which case you'll see a dialog where you'll need to select all projects that you want to import. This approach allows importing multiple projects in a single import.

Eclipse finds projects by searching for '.project' files in all sub-directories of the root folder that you've provided.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. I faced a similar situation earlier. Just follow these steps :

1. Copy the project to the other desktop.
2. Go to File -> Import -> General -> Existing Projects into workspace.
3. Browse and select your project folder and import the files.